# How to "flatten" a Panda Panel by summing up specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am still familairizing myself with Pandas, and Python in general, so please excuse if this is a simple question.  I'd also like to avoid one liners so I can understand the underlying actions if possible! :)

I've managed to pull data data which results in a Panel, with four items.  The key of each item is a calendar quarter:

```
Item '2015-03-31':
Type        Quarterly Sales        Ending Inventory
Shoes       123,456                50,000
Purses      33,222                 10,000

Item '2015-06-30':
Type        Quarterly Sales        Ending Inventory
Shoes       12,744                 56,000
Purses      15,123                 9,000

Item '2015-9-30':
Type        Quarterly Sales        Ending Inventory
Shoes       15,998                 35,000
Purses      11,222                 15,000

Item '2015-12-31':
Type        Quarterly Sales        Ending Inventory
Shoes       12,000                 45,000
Purses      9,551                  7,000
```

Ultimately, I would like to "flatten" this by summing up the **Quarterly Sales**, but taking the **Type** and **Ending Inventory** from the most recent entry, and have this in a DataFrame.  So my ending DataFrame would be something like this:

```
Type        Quarterly Sales        Ending Inventory
Shoes       164,198                45,000
Purses      69,118                 7,000
```

I tried using a function such as grouby (e.g. `mypanel.groupby('Type').sum()`), but that ended up summing both **Quarterly Sales** *and* **Ending Inventory**, whereas I want to take the "most recent" **Ending Inventory** instead.  An easy "fix" for this would be to take the resulting DataFrame, and then subtract out the summation of the first three quarters for the **Ending Inventory** column, but that seems incredibly awkward.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: try this: `mypanel.groupby('Type').agg({'Quarterly Sales':'sum', 'Ending Inventory':'last'})`

Answer (score 0):

```
agg_dict = {'Quarterly Sales': 'sum', 'Ending Inventory': 'last'}
pnl.to_frame().T.stack(0).groupby(level='Type').agg(agg_dict)
```

[image]